# Unresolved method/variable in Webstorm prototype functions

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I recently switched to WebStorm and I'm stuck on an odd problem with javascript prototype modifications. If I define the following:

```
something.really.neat = function(blah) {
    this.dog = "cat"
}

something.really.neat.prototype.getCow = function(blah2) {
    this.dog = "cow"
}
```

Every single call to this.dog in a prototype function results in an "Unresolved variable" error. WebStorm should easily be able to follow the scope from the prototype to the main function but it seems unable to.

The end result of this function is an angular factory:

```
angular.factory('neat', function() {
    return new something.really.neat();
});
```

Comment: Does it only happen when you have put the constructor in a `something.really.` namespace? Does it work when you capitalize `Neat`? Does the code actually work (and only the "type" inference is shouting warnings)?

Comment: Does it really warn about "unresolved *variable*"? `.dog` is a *property*, and `this` is the *context* not the *scope* of the method.

Comment: It said unresolved variable dog, probably because the this context didn't have a property dog. That said, I managed to track down the problem.

Comment: This should help in understanding the error: [Scope in JavaScript](https://mikewest.org/2006/09/scope-in-javascript). Mike West is a good author.

Answer (score 0):

5 minutes later I discover its a problem with JSDoc (or at least my syntax). I was using @memberOf on each property and it apparently the syntax I was using for @memberOf was wrong, resulting in WebStorm not being able to locate the scope.